# se puede crear el archivo google_maps_api.xml

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

Estoy haciendo pruebas con un mapa y cuando lo cree el Google Maps Activity uno de los archivos que se crea en la carpeta `Value` es el  **google_maps_api.xml** para obtener la Key, la puse y he estado haciendo pruebas, y todo ha funcionado bien, pero hoy sigo con las pruebas y veo que nada mas entrar al mapa me muestra un error y se cierra, como no entiendo muy bien los errores que muestra, he revisado las partes del mapa, y me he dado cuenta que **AndroidManifest.xml** no hay ninguna referencia a la KEY, y veo que el **google_maps_api.xml** tampoco esta.

Se pueden recuperas estos datos que faltan de alguna forma ?

Gracias.

Comment: En tu pregunta sería de mucha utilidad a la comunidad si agregaras el error que se muestra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si puedes hacer referencia de forma a tu `google_maps_api`, en tu `Manifest` debes incluir el tag:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Tu API Key debe estar en un archivo xml en la carpeta values,en caso que no lo tengas lo puedes crear:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y contener la key de la siguiente forma:

```
<resources>   
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIzweyrrfd59Tzw0NEAbtkgn5o511xDCthgRNo</string>
```

(Ese solo es un ejemplo tu debes colocar tu key, la cual encuentras en la [console google](https://console.cloud.google.com) )

Comment: Ya esta otra vez funcionando, no se porque desaparecieron, muchas gracias Igmer

Answer (score 0):

**La definición de la API_KEY en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` así como el archivo `google_maps_api.xml` no deberían desaparecer ya que son recursos de solo lectura, a menos que tu mismo elimines esta información.**

Primeramente tienes que tener el metadato el cual definira la API Key que permitirá visualizar los mapas, si no tienes esta definición debes agregarla dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <application>
   ...
   ...
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
   ...
   ...
   </application>
```

Para definir el API KEY puedes usar cualquiera de estas opciones:

Definir el valor de la API Key en tu archivo `/res/values/strings.xml` , ejemplo:

```
<resources>

    <string name="google_maps_key">xJADASBRENBESDASGTEBTRNRTNREENTENTEWESAASSA</string>

</resources>
```

O usar el archivo `google_maps_api.xml`
Con respecto a el archivo `google_maps_api.xml`,  `Android Studio` incluye una plantilla de Google Maps Activity. El código de la plantilla incluye un archivo `google_maps_api.xml` que contiene un enlace que simplifica la obtención de una clave API.

Si no existe, puedes crearlo y agregar ahí tu API Key

```
<resources>

    <string name="google_maps_key">xJADASBRENBESDASGTEBTRNRTNREENTENTEWESAASSA</string>

</resources>
```

*Puedes usar cualquiera de las 2 opciones para obtener el valor del API KEY.